# max and min of $f(x,y)=\int_{x}^{y} e^{-t^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to study max e min of this function on $C=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\le1\}$

$\nabla f(x,y)=(-e^{-x^2},e^{-y^2})$ so there isn't max and min in C because the gradient isn't null.
But on the boundary of C?

Comment: your function is positive on C and independent of x and y. so you have to simply max the integration domain with x<y. for the min value vise versa.

Comment: if I parametrized the boundary in polar coordinates i have $f(cos\theta,sin\theta)=G(sin\theta)-G(cos\theta)=h(\theta)$ $h'(\theta)=$?

Comment: How the functions G and h are defined?

Comment: G is the primitive function

Comment: ah okay, but you can not calculate G? what properties does G have thought?

Comment: I can calculate $h'(\theta)=G'(sin\theta) cos\theta -G'(cos\theta) (-sin\theta)=e^{-(sin\theta)^2} cos\theta + e^{-(cos\theta)^2} sin\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either by using Lagrange multipliers or by parameterizing $f$ on the boundary by the angle $\theta$ reduces the problem to solving the following equation:
$$
\cos\theta e^{-sin^2\theta} = -\sin\theta e^{-cos^2\theta}$$
This can be rewritten as $$ -\tan\theta = e^{\cos2\theta}$$
We first note that there are no solutions with $\theta \in (0,\pi/2)$ since on this interval $-\tan\theta <0$.  On the interval $(-\pi/2, 0)$ we have that $e^{\cos2\theta}$ is increasing and $-\tan\theta$ is decreasing, so there is at most one point of intersection, which by inspection is at $\theta = -\pi/4$.  Since both equations are $\pi$-periodic, the solutions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ are given by $\theta = -\pi/4, 3\pi/4$.  These correspond to the points $(\sqrt{2}/2, -\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $(-\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

I formulate my approach as an answer.

You already stated that there are no inner solutions. Observe that $exp(-t^2)$ is always positive, and symmetric via $t=0$(which is also its maximum value). So given these facts we just have to maximize the integration domain $[x,y]$ subject to C. (Why?)

$max ~ y-x$ s.t. $x^2+y^2=1$

which solution is $x= -\sqrt{1/2}$, $y= \sqrt{1/2}$

for the minimum value you just have to flip the signs.

Sorry, this is a bit short. I hope you can follow my steps.

Greetings.